# How to turn off Core Data Write-Ahead logging in Swift using options dictionary?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

How do I turn off the SQLite Write ahead logging (WAL) in Core Data using Apples new programming language Swift?

In ObjC I used to pass in the key value pair @"journal_mode": @"DELETE" in the options dictionary:

```
[storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                               configuration:nil
                                         URL:[self databaseURL]
                                     options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                                           NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                                           @"journal_mode": @"DELETE"}
                                       error:&error]
```

But in Swift only the same types are allowed in a NSDictionary, so mixing BOOL (that is mapped to NSNumber) and NSString is not possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift dictionaries are strongly typed by default, but you can define the types your dictionary should accept.

```
var options = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = true
options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = true
options["journal_mode"] = "DELETE"

[storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                               configuration:nil
                                         URL:[self databaseURL]
                                     options:opitons
                                       error:&error]
```

If you weren't sure what type of dictionary the function was expecting, just take a look at the [function declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:) :

```
func addPersistentStoreWithType(_ storeType: String!,
   configuration configuration: String!,
       URL storeURL: NSURL!,
    options options: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
        error error: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>) -> NSPersistentStore!
```

It describes exactly the type of dictionary it expects -- `Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>`.

In fact, any dictionary that is bridged from Objective-C will be typed this way. From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html):

> Swift also automatically bridges between the Dictionary type and the
> NSDictionary class. When you bridge from an NSDictionary object to a
> Swift dictionary, the resulting dictionary is of type [NSObject:
> AnyObject].
>
> You can bridge any NSDictionary object to a Swift
> dictionary because all Objective-C objects are AnyObject compatible.
> Recall that an object is AnyObject compatible if it is an instance of
> an Objective-C or Swift class, or if it can be bridged to one. All
> NSDictionary objects can be bridged to Swift dictionaries, so the
> Swift compiler replaces the NSDictionary class with [NSObject:
> AnyObject] when it imports Objective-C APIs.
>
> Likewise, when you use a
> Swift class or protocol in Objective-C code, the importer remaps
> Objective-C compatible Swift dictionaries as NSDictionary objects.

Answer (score 7):

These answers were close but neither were actually working for me. The following does work. The option must be as as a `NSSQLitePragmasOption`.

```
var options = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = true
options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = true
options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = ["journal_mode" : "DELETE"]
if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options, error: &error) == nil {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One hint, make sure you pass a Dictionary into NSSQLitePragmasOption. e.g.

```
url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(name, withExtension: "momd")
let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: url!)!)

var err: NSError? = nil
url = dataDir.URLByAppendingPathComponent(name + ".sqlite")
options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true, NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"]]
coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options, error: &err)
```